# Ruby on Rails - simple_form fields_for create different index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, fields-for

I have a question about updating `one-to-many fields` using `simple_form field_for` method

I have 2 models, `Company` and `Clients`, which has a `one-to-many` relationship.
I displayed clients using `field_for`, but for UI reason, I had to called it twice. 
But for some reason, the index of the input fields was given a different value. Below is my code

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Company name: ' %>               
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :clients do |client| %>
      <%= client.input :name, label: 'Client names: ' %>               
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :info, label: 'Company info: ' %>               
    </td> 
    <td class="span2 clients_desc">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :clients do |client| %>          
      <%= client.input :description, label: 'Client description: ' %>          
    <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Say if I had 3 clients, the output for the name of the `input fields` became

`company[client_attributes][0][name]`, `company[client_attributes][1][name]`, `company[client_attributes][2][name]`

and

`company[client_attributes][3][description]`,  `company[client_attributes][4][description]`,  `company[client_attributes][5][description]`

This result in duplicating clients during store. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why you are calling it **twice**? Why not wrap them into a **single** `simple_fields_for`?

Comment: It's for UI reason, there are some other information I had to display within that table

Comment: What is that **UI** reason? Can you explain a bit more please.

Comment: The code I put here isn't a exact replicate of my code, the UI requires a table which had 1 column that contain some company information as well as the name of all the clients. Whereas another column which contain some other information from all the clients. It's a weird design I know, but I didn't designed it.

Comment: I've updated my code so it makes more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy workaround would be "caching" the form fields like so:

```
# ...
<%= f.simple_fields_for :clients do |client| %>
  <%= client.input :name, label: 'Client names: ' %>
  <% client_description_input = client.input :description, label: 'Client description: ' %>          
<% end %>
# ...
<%= client_description_input %>
# ...
```